# Threads not terminating and slaves not running together (c++)

Tags: c++, multithreading, terminate

I am writing a program where a master runs, does something, awakes two slaves and waits, slaves do something, awake master and so on. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>
#include <mutex>
#include <chrono>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <thread>

using namespace std;

bool blue_slave_go=false, yellow_slave_go=false, done=false;


void master_execution(mutex & master_mtx, condition_variable & master_convar, condition_variable & slaves_convar){
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(master_mtx);
    int counter=0;
    std::cout<<"Master thread initialized"<<std::endl;
    while (counter<2){
    std::cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Master thread starting task..."<<std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    yellow_slave_go = true;
    blue_slave_go = true;
    slaves_convar.notify_all();
    master_convar.wait(lock);
    std::cout<<"Master thread awaken..."<<std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
    ++counter;
    std::cout<<"Master finishing task..."<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<"----------------------------------------"<<std::endl;
    }
}

void yellow_slave_execution(mutex & slaves_mutex, condition_variable & slaves_convar, condition_variable & master_convar){
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(slaves_mutex);
    std::cout<<"Creating thread..."<<std::endl;
    while(1){
        if(!blue_slave_go){
            std::cout<<"Waking up master..."<<std::endl;
            master_convar.notify_one();

        }
        slaves_convar.wait(lock);
        std::cout<<"Yellow thread starting task..."<<std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        yellow_slave_go=false;
        std::cout<<"Yellow thread finishing task..."<<std::endl;
    }
}

void blue_slave_execution(mutex & slaves_mutex, condition_variable & slaves_convar, condition_variable & master_convar){
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(slaves_mutex);
    std::cout<<"Creating thread..."<<std::endl;
    while(1){
        if(!yellow_slave_go){
            std::cout<<"Waking up master..."<<std::endl;
            master_convar.notify_one();

        }
        slaves_convar.wait(lock);
        std::cout<<"Blue thread starting task..."<<std::endl;
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(3));
        blue_slave_go=false;
        std::cout<<"Blue thread finishing task..."<<std::endl;
    }
}
int main(){
    mutex master_mtx, slaves_mutex;
    condition_variable master_convar, slaves_convar;

    thread master{master_execution, ref(master_mtx),ref(master_convar), ref(slaves_convar)};
    thread blue_slave{blue_slave_execution, ref(slaves_mutex),ref(slaves_convar), ref(master_convar)};
    thread yellow_slave{yellow_slave_execution, ref(slaves_mutex),ref(slaves_convar), ref(master_convar)};

    blue_slave.join();
    yellow_slave.join();
    master.join();
    blue_slave.detach();
    yellow_slave.detach();
    master.detach();

    std::cout<<"EXECUTION DONE!!!"<<std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I am getting the following output:

```
> Creating thread... 
> Waking up master... 
> Creating thread...
> Waking up master... 
> Master thread initialized
> ---------------------------------------- 
> Master thread starting task... 
> Yellow thread starting task... 
> Yellow thread finishing task...
> Blue thread starting task... 
> Blue thread finishing task... 
> Waking up master... 
> Master thread awaken... 
> Master finishing task...
> ----------------------------------------
> ---------------------------------------- 
> Master thread starting task... 
> Yellow thread starting task... 
> Yellow thread finishing task...
> Blue thread starting task... 
> Blue thread finishing task... 
> Waking up master... 
> Master thread awaken... 
> Master finishing task...
> ----------------------------------------
```

So basically I have two problems. The first one is that the slaves are not running at the same time, one starts and finishes an then the other goes on, and I want them to run together.
The second issue I have is that the program does not end and I don't know why as I thought threads were killed when done.
Hope you can help me.

Comment: why do you `detach` all the threads?

Comment: your threads run a `while(1)`, you never `break` out of those loops

Comment: @PeteBeck ah ok, sorry

Comment: @user463035818 -- it's okay; this is **very** confusing code.

Comment: I would strongly suggst to cut down complexity by making `yellow_slave_execution` and `blue_slave_execution` the same function (they are almost identical anyhow)

Comment: do the slaves actually share anything? I dont understand why you need that many mutexes and condition variable etc

Comment: That isn't how to use `condition_variable`s. That isn't how to use `detach`.  That isn't how you use `mutex`es.  I don't think you are using a single C++ threading primitive in a way that they are intended.  On top of that, your code is the threading equivalent of spaghetti code; mutexes and locks and signals flying all over the place with data modification scattered throughout.  I'd be shocked if your program's behavior was defined.  Back up.  Write some primitives like a thread-safe message queue or a thread pool.  You are using low level building blocks in "business logic" code, that is bad

Comment: `detach()` or `join()`, but don't do both. A `thread` object is not a _thread_. It is your program's _handle_ on a thread. The `std::thread` class wants to help you by ensuring that you don't destroy that handle while the thread still is running... Unless you declare that that really is what you intend by calling `detach()`.  But, `join()` won't return until the thread is finished.  So, if your code calls both `detach()` and `join()` on the same thread, then your intent becomes very unclear.